# How to set semi transparency to background, but not foreground for wp8?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, compact-framework

I'm creating a customize loading message and I would like to set the background to semi-transparent only. The issue I'm having is that the whole stackpanel is set to semi-transparent including background and foreground. How can I make only the background semi-transparent and leave foreground the way it is? Below is my xaml code.

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="spLoading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
            <Border Margin="5" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" Opacity=".1" CornerRadius="10">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtLoading" Foreground="White" Text="loading . . ." HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="5" />
            </Border>                
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

This would do the required.

```
<Border Margin="5" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10">
            <Border.Background>
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.1" />
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBlock />
</Border>
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for, but couldn't figured out the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome :). And if this answers your question you should mark it as answer so that other people can also get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want that the background of the border has somekind of opacity, the way to do that is play with the alpha channel of the background of the border like:

```
<Border Background="#3000"...>
```

Or

```
 <Border Background="#33000000"...>
```

You can use in the colors everywhere, in your case:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="spLoading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
        <Border Margin="5" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#33000000" Background="#33000000"  CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtLoading" Foreground="White" Text="loading . . ." HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="5" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
```

With that you have the border background and stroke semitransparent

Comment: Actually, I just want "Loading" to have a solid color, but everything else is semi-transparent.

Comment: I think the code should be something like this, but not sure what is the correct synatx.         <Border.Background> some logic inside </Border.Background>

Comment: You mean the stroke and the background of the border like I added?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Rectangle   Opacity="0.4" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
        <StackPanel Background="White"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Margin="20,10,20,10">Loading...</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

What this does, is that the Grid take the full space available, the rectangle gives you the grey scale (opacity), and the stackpanel just works as is.

(Note this is what I do in WPF)